# Failure certificate request generated on the Power System (AS/400) to Apple

Tags: request, certificate, ibm-midrange

We have recently faced an issue using our IBM Power System (AS/400), we are not able to get accepted our certificate request (CSR) on the Apple website. To be more specific, I am talking about the push certification autority (https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/) for the generation of the relevant push notification certification.
The massage we receive on screen is as following:
"The Certificate Signing Request you entered appears to be invalid. Make sure that request file uploaded is in the correct format and not empty."
This kind of message has been obtained by the Power System Digital Certificate Manager calling the function "Create Certificate". We have followed exactly the same procedure that we have always been used to follow for comparable certificates request of no Apple websites. Those requests have always had received positive response.
To solve this issue we called the Apple Assistance. According to them, the problem is about the certificate request format, which seems to appear not correct. However, on the Power System environment should not exist a different way or procedure for creating a certificate request.
The contents of the .csr file is as follows:

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

According to you, Is possibile that those certificate requests generated by the Power System can not be valid and therefore accepted by the Apple Certificate Authority?
Is there anyone who recently developed the Apple Push Notification service on IBM  Power System and could help us in figuring out and find out a solution?

Comment: You should mention what OS version you're on, if you're up on PTFs, etc.  A lot has changed in the SSL/TLS arena over the last few years, and it's possible you're generating CSRs that aren't compatible with the new higher security SSL certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to verify the csr without any issue. It was generated using SHA1 which is being deprecated and may be the issue.

```
$ openssl -req -text -noout -verify -in test.csr

verify OK
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=IT, ST=Roma, L=Roma, O=Bios, OU=Bios, CN=com.biosspa.Bios
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a5:f0:8f:64:ab:29:81:ad:26:ef:b7:36:7b:1d:
                    6d:6e:5b:bd:b7:75:ac:65:11:3e:32:21:53:7a:4b:
                    78:2c:91:9a:25:80:f4:ca:73:7e:69:ee:4a:f1:ca:
                    e6:d8:23:78:5d:29:02:97:e2:70:e9:5d:0a:f5:8e:
                    d2:ff:d6:6d:cb:59:32:d4:d2:ea:3c:09:98:b5:12:
                    92:6c:d3:9f:91:35:1c:22:05:63:c0:63:94:c1:26:
                    77:3d:d8:82:cb:84:88:5d:df:52:b3:2d:fa:08:42:
                    b2:e9:eb:f3:d6:7a:e1:37:ba:6b:d0:c2:81:6b:f1:
                    d3:34:e5:ae:b2:db:2c:37:e7:57:50:fc:d8:c9:7f:
                    dd:4a:b1:8a:8f:a9:32:34:36:29:70:89:7a:00:63:
                    f0:70:95:32:a2:fa:c6:62:c4:98:2d:9c:75:b6:68:
                    3f:6f:9c:dd:65:8a:a8:d2:69:39:e7:78:f9:5e:00:
                    5b:3a:f0:e4:e7:b5:1a:5e:2d:78:e5:42:fe:6f:fd:
                    59:8a:c1:f9:2b:4d:fb:97:0b:4b:7c:b7:eb:9b:2d:
                    c2:b2:11:fd:41:c8:c2:3b:05:b9:48:11:53:0c:e1:
                    e5:8d:7c:2d:db:48:bb:a9:a9:98:4c:d1:73:0f:8a:
                    3a:21:eb:38:f4:97:4f:32:1b:86:24:c4:76:98:35:
                    3a:c5
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
            a0:00
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         47:9d:73:3a:10:c2:2e:28:c9:b8:e2:b5:9c:d9:27:c4:f6:89:
         6a:04:c9:fb:60:2e:d1:23:a8:dc:a8:68:69:23:e7:7b:63:a5:
         f9:20:da:22:41:2c:65:a4:6f:45:8d:1a:5e:ab:2c:78:de:b6:
         75:ec:b7:e9:fe:f1:9b:f7:33:45:75:aa:ea:9b:23:7e:3e:80:
         8f:e4:92:9c:92:31:df:d2:7f:c5:22:98:9e:ef:f4:25:1d:2c:
         c8:c9:02:76:e1:e2:2f:f6:aa:a2:44:57:6e:a8:6f:de:f7:85:
         ad:e5:a3:65:a5:8b:d1:6f:bc:62:2d:c6:2e:2d:29:4f:20:c9:
         dd:5c:b2:4b:b7:29:11:f0:d6:5e:e8:6f:71:a8:ff:a7:58:bd:
         7b:08:d1:05:1a:6e:c1:5a:1e:d7:31:a5:d3:62:12:23:10:b7:
         c3:de:66:77:de:31:1c:d1:61:9e:f7:ba:5c:d1:28:1f:77:cf:
         a9:5b:b6:a6:e4:ec:44:4a:c2:52:90:6a:c0:e6:5b:74:8b:89:
         ff:e1:49:8d:e2:3d:ef:a8:77:77:2b:53:c8:03:e2:65:9e:c4:
         75:10:92:61:fe:ef:5e:c5:8f:44:7a:0c:d2:3a:30:b7:9c:f0:
         9f:fb:73:67:8f:25:2d:60:5c:e3:59:e8:a0:f5:0f:95:3a:3f:
         ea:db:e0:ea
```